# turning json hash to keys on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to access the hash values from a JSON file from a url to my views.

```
 def index
    require "net/http"
    source = 'http://exampleabcd.json'
    resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(source))
    data = resp.body
    thishash = JSON.parse(data)
    @array = thishas.map{ |k,v| { k.to_sym => v }}
  end
```

After adding `.map{ |k,v| { k.to_sym => v }}` this returns an array that looks like this

```
{:John=>{"id"=>"1", "key"=>"266", "name"=>"John", "title"=>"manager"}},
{:Alice=>{"id"=>"2", "key"=>"267", "name"=>"Alice", "title"=>"staff"}},
etc...
```

then on my index.html.erb, I try to access the values with

```
<% @array.each do |person| %>
   <span> <%= person[:keyhere] %> </span
 <% end %>
```

I can only access get the value of the first value of array like [:John], and if I try to do person[:title], I get an error.

How do I make the inside hash to look like this so I can access them on my index.html.erb such as `person[:title]`

```
{:John=>{:id=>"1", :key=>"266", :name=>"John", :title=>"manager"}},
```

Comment: Why are you doing `thishas.map{ |k,v| { k.to_sym => v }}` at all?

Comment: You can replace the last two lines of `index` with `JSON.parse(data, symbolize_names: true)`. See [JSON::parse](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this specific scenario, Rails has a built in method for that: [`Hash#symbolize_keys!`](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/symbolize_keys%21). So you could do:

```
@array = JSON.parse(data).symbolize_keys
```

However, we can even take this a step back and get a hash with symbols in the first place from [`JSON.parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse):

```
@array = JSON.parse(data, symbolize_names: true)
```

This is the best approach here. Use that. (I'd also strongly advise using a more descriptive variable name than `@array`!!)

---

In general, when dealing this problem of transforming the keys of a hash, Rails once again has a built-in method for this: [`Hash#transform_keys`](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/transform_keys). So, you *could* also have done something like:

```
@array = JSON.parse(data).transform_keys(&:to_sym)
```

(But as explained above, there are specialised methods for this common use case.)

This `transform_keys` method was also [added to Ruby `v2.5.0`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys) (released in December 2017). If you wish to transform the keys of a hash in some other custom manner, are using an older version of ruby and are not using rails (ActiveSupport), then you can `map` the values like you did above and then convert the result back into a `Hash`:

```
@array = JSON.parse(data).map { |k, v| [k.to_sym, v] }.to_h
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop with array.length as limit and in loop you can use array[i].title, array[i].key and whatever you need (i is looping variable)